# Django: overriding save() method in model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override the `save()` method so that the field `views` of class `Category` accepts only positive numbers or zero. (It's an exercise from [Tango with Django 1.7 Chapter 20](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/test.html))

**models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        if self.views < 0:
            return
        else:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

**test.py:**

```
class CategoryMethodTests(TestCase):
    def test_ensure_views_are_positive(self):
        """
        ensure_views_are_positive should return True for categories where views are zero or positive
        """
        cat = Category(name='test', views=-1, like=0)
        cat.save()
        self.assertEqual((cat.views >= 0), True)
```

Even if I added the condition `if self.views < 0` in `models.py` the test failed:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_ensure_views_are_positive (rango.tests.CategoryMethodTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pm/tango_project/rango/tests.py", line 11, in test_ensure_views_are_positive
    self.assertEqual((cat.views >= 0), True)
AssertionError: False != True

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why self.assertEqual() use self.assertTrue(), and Django has PositiveIntegertField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` is an object in python. It doesn't change unless you explicitly change it. Your database won't have `cat` in it, and your test should be:

```
self.assertEqual(Category.objects.count(), 0)
```

But the variable `cat` will exist in that scope as you created it nevertheless.

When you test `cat.views`, it only check the value of the `views` field in the `cat` instance that you've just created. This has nothing to do with your DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you could do easily. First point is

- you could use **Positive integer field** in Django, if you want only positive integer in this model
- if you want to do the custom way, please raise an exception or use the assert statement for it. Then in the test case could check whether exception or assertion Error is raised